# Treat NULL as character in QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qbytearray

I am using QT4.8 and I need to send an array to another device which includes some `0x00` values. However, QByteArray treats `0x00` value as of the end of the string. I wonder if it is even possible, what I am trying to achieve. here is my test code:-

```
zeroissue::zeroissue(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    unsigned char zero = 0x00;
    QByteArray test;
    test.append("this is a test");
    test.append(zero);
    test.append("test complete");
    qDebug() << "test = " << test;
}
```

Please suggest me a way to treat `0x00` as a character in QByteArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it is even possible,

Yes, it is. From [QByteArray's documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details):

> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings.

The following `main` funtion works as expected

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char null_char = '\0';
   QByteArray test;
   test.append("this is a test");
   std::cout << "size(): " << test.size() << std::endl;

   test.append(null_char);
   std::cout << "size(): " << test.size() << std::endl;

   test.append("test complete");
   std::cout << "size(): " << test.size() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

and produces the following expected output:

```
size(): 14
size(): 15
size(): 28
```

When you use

```
qDebug() << "test = " << test;
```

you should see the embedded null character in the output. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-20 for additional details.